# Unsound behavior with -rte option in Magnesium

Tags: frama-c

I am facing an incoherent behavior with the `-rte` option in Magnesium version (installed directly from ubuntu). I am wondering if someone is aware of that problem or if I am doing something wrong.

I have a program with an incorrect acces outside an array. When lauching `frama-c-gui` with no options and value analysis, the out-of-bounds access is detected and the corresponding annotation is displayed with an orange circle. When using the -rte option, two annotations are displayed (for the lower and upper bound of the array), and a green circle is displayed for both (which is incorrect).

```
/*@ assert rte: index_bound: 0 ≤ cpt; */
/*@ assert rte: index_bound: cpt < 5; */
```

The console says :

```
tableau_erreur.c:11:[value] Assertion 'rte,index_bound' got status valid.
```

I suspect there is a mismatch between the two annotations because they both have the same "name" : `index_bound`.

Also, the part of code after the loop containing the faulty access is colored in red, suggesting that the analysis correctly inferred that it is not reachable because of an error before.

Here is my program :

```
int main(){
  int t[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int cpt =0 ;
  int tmp ;
  while  (cpt<10){
    tmp = getchar() ;
    if ( t[cpt] > tmp )
      { return 1  ;  }
    cpt++ ;
  }
  return 10 ;
}
```

Here is a capture of my display (using `frama-c-gui -rte tableau_erreur.c`).

[image: incorrect green circle on second annotation]

When I do not use the `-rte` option the result is correct (orange circle) :

[image: Correct version without -rte]

I had a look at the bug tracker but did not find trace of that. I did not manage to compile a more recent version of Frama-C to test it.

Comment: On a side note, it is always useful to know when users are having trouble installing Frama-C. It could be an issue with OPAM, or something else, but someone in the frama-c-discuss list (frama-c-discuss@lists.gforge.inria.fr) might be able to help.

Comment: This is indeed a major bug, that will be fixed ASAP. Thanks for taking the time to report it, here on SO and on the Frama-C BTS. Regarding your question "am I doing something wrong", the answer is no _per se_, but it is unusual to use Value and RTE together. (Which is why this bug wen unnoticed for so long.) Out of curiosity, do you have a particular reason to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: this behavior has been fixed in the Silicon release of Frama-C (the status associated to assertion `rte: index_bound: cpt < 5` remains *unknown*).

---

I couldn't reproduce *exactly* what you said, but after launching the GUI as in your command, *then* clicking on the "Run" button in the Value analysis panel, I got the green bullets.

This is equivalent to running `frama-c-gui -rte -then -val`, which also displays the green (incorrect) bullets.

Indeed this seems to be an issue even in the current Frama-C version, so a bug report is in order. Note that manually inserting an equivalent annotation (`//@ assert cpt < 5;`) does result in an yellow bullet, as expected. Also, unrolling the loop (with `-slevel 5`, for instance) also results in an yellow bullet. The issue seems to be related specifically to the usage of the RTE plug-in, but in any case it will be investigated.

On a side note, the `index_bound` label next to the property is not an identifier, just a label, hence not unique, and unrelated to the issue here.

**Technical details**: Frama-C has notions of *properties* and *statuses*, which are summarized by the bullets next to the source code, but described in more detail either through the *Properties* panel (you may need to modify some filters and click on the *Refresh* button to see them) or the Report plug-in (e.g. `frama-c -val -then -report`). In your example, the first iteration of the loop has a value of `cpt` that is 0, therefore the property acquires a `valid` status (green bullet), and in the last iteration (when `cpt` is 5) it gets a `unknown` status (yellow bullet). For some reason it was (incorrectly) consolidated as `valid`, hence the green bullet. The Value log does however display `file.c:8:[value] warning: assertion 'rte,index_bound' got status unknown`, which shows up in the Messages panel in the GUI. This does not explain the error, but the combination of both Messages and Properties panels is a powerful tool to diagnose issues with properties.

Comment: Thank you, I will report the bug.